# How to add the sum of the 'sum of the two tables?'

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, sum

I created Tables T1 and T2. I managed to add their sum, but I can't seem to add the sum of the T1 and T2 together (10+12 = **22**)  by adding a sum() in the beginning of the code.

```
    CREATE TABLE T1(kW int)
    CREATE TABLE T2(kW int) 

    SELECT T1C1, T2C1
    FROM
     ( select SUM(Kw) T1C1 FROM  T1 ) A
    CROSS JOIN 
     ( select SUM(Kw) T2C1 FROM  T2 ) B

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('4');
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('1');
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('5');
    INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('7');
    INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('2');
    INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('3');
    END
```

Comment: (10+12 = 22) sorry

Comment: I don't understand. You have three answers, all doing different things; but, in the query **YOU** tried, what is wrong with adding `, T1C1 + T2C1 as sum_of_both_tables` to the outer `SELECT` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `union all` to create a "virtual" column from the columns in the two tables:

```
SELECT SUM(kw)
FROM   (SELECT kw FROM t1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT kw FROM t2) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a stored procedure. Doing so you will be able to store the sum of each table on a separated variable and then return the SUM of those two variables.

You can also make a `UNION ALL` and `SUM` the column you want. Notice that you should a `UNION ALL` to avoid eliminating duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add the results of the two subqueries directly, using the built-in dummy table `dual` as the main driving table:

```
select ( select SUM(Kw) FROM T1 )
     + ( select SUM(Kw) FROM T2 ) as total
from dual;

     TOTAL
----------
        22
```